# bs4: search for special characters like 'ä'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to search for text in a webpage with characters like 'ä' bs4 does not correctly encode these and I can thus not correctly search the site. For example

```
 <td>
     <a href="/gy/area/name/1208.html">täkäen</a>

soup.findAll(text='täkäen') - does not work
```

I've also tried to search for the .html string (below) but this also seems not to work.

```
soup.findAll(text='/gy/area/name/1208.html')
```

Would anyone know how to correctly encode the webpage when I read it or simply search the above code for "/gy/area/name/1208.html"

Thanks

Comment: "does not work": Exceptions or nothing found?

Comment: When you get the http response, can you read the encoding as part of the response header? If so, decode the response to unicode with the encoding.

Comment: Show us how you are getting the HTML source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for *unicode* values:

```
soup.findAll(text=u'täkäen')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
...  <td>
...      <a href="/gy/area/name/1208.html">täkäen</a>
... ''')
>>> soup
<html><body><td>
<a href="/gy/area/name/1208.html">täkäen</a></td></body></html>
>>> soup.findAll(text=u'täkäen')
[u't\xe4k\xe4en']
```

You need to make sure you set the source code encoding correctly, or use unicode escape codes.

Comment: Actually, it works both ways. I bet the real issue is encoding of the HTML source.